# Meteor: Iterate over nested elements

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

**UPDATE**

I updated the question:

I have got this result of a collection, which I want to use in my template. So I iterate with the each-spacebar.
The problem is, that I want to get all article-datasets and complete the output with the journal-field.

```
{
    "journal" : "journalSingle",
    "article" : [
        {
            "title" : "title1",
            "edition" : "test",
            "reference" : "4NoHjACkjHJ8mavv9"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "journal" : "multiple",
    "article" : [
        {
            "title" : "title2",
            "edition" : "test",
            "reference" : "4NoHjACkjHJ8mavv9"
        },
        {
            "title" : "title3",
            "edition" : "test",
            "reference" : "4NoHjACkjHJ8mavv9"
        }
    ]
}
```

**template**

```
{{#each item}}
    <div>
        <input data-field="journal" type="text" value="{{journal}}">
        <input data-field="edition" type="text" value="{{article.title}}">
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

The result should be for that example:

```
<div>
    <input data-field="journal" type="text" value="journalSingle">
    <input data-field="edition" type="text" value="title1">
</div>
<div>
    <input data-field="journal" type="text" value="multiple">
    <input data-field="edition" type="text" value="title2">
</div>
<div>
    <input data-field="journal" type="text" value="multiple">
    <input data-field="edition" type="text" value="title3">
</div>
```

Comment: `each` only iterates over a single level in an array - it doesn't recursively traverse an object structure. A precise answer could be written if you show an example template and what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because article is an array you can't go   `article.title`.

```
 {{#each item}}
    <input data-field="journal" type="text" value="{{journal}}">
    {{#each article}}
         <input data-field="edition" type="text" value="{{title}}">
    {{/each}}
   {{/each}}
```

you can do this, but it is weird you can edit journal in multiple places

```
 {{#each item}}

    {{#each article}}
       <div>
         <input data-field="journal" type="text" value="{{..journal}}">
         <input data-field="edition" type="text" value="{{title}}">
       </div>
    {{/each}}
   {{/each}}
```

Comment: Ah, you are right, that's an array, I didn't see that. So what can I do with that?

Comment: My problem is, that both input fields belong together. That means, if there are two journal-entries (like in the first example) and one of this journal has two article-entries (like in the second example), I need totally the output of 3x these two input-fields.

Comment: But your data structure doesn't support that.   your data has a journal, with multiple articles, and each article has multiple details, of which edition is a property,  you might have many many "editions" per journal.

Comment: You can however go 3 layers deep in your model. `{{#each references}}...{{#each this.article}}...{#each this.detail}}`

Comment: updated again to give the html you wanted, but, it is weird, because you can't edit journal to be different for different articles because you can't store that in your data structure